# Sign electronically generated PDF with JSPDF in Angular

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf, signature

I have Angular app witch generates PDFS and i can save them on my server.

My question is,

is there any way the user can sign digitally the document, before saving it?

I generate the PDF using jsPDF

I do not think a code here would be useful i just want to know some possible solutions how a user can sign online generated PDF before saving it on the server.

Of course, to download the document, sign it and upload it again works, but the idea is to be able to do everything in the browser

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you should checkout this example: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2022/how-to-insert-a-digital-signature-in-a-pdf-using-javascript/